# Blog posts are being listed under content

Tags: nodes

I know nothing about Drupal, trying to help a friend out.

Right now blog posts are being listed under `/content` [`site.com/content/blog-post-title`] instead of `/blog`.

I'm trying to figure out where to look to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `blog-post-title` appears suggests that the module **PathAuto** is somehow involved.  Try to disable that module (If you're on Drupal 7, navigate to *Home » Administration » Modules*, locate **PathAuto** and remove its tickmark, then press "Save configuration" and clear all caches.)

If the blog posts now appear under `/blog`, you know why.

After you've etablished that **PathAuto** is indeed resposible, you can re-enable the module (all its settings will be left intact), and you can then proceed to change its settings to put blog posts in the place you want them.

Comment: I will never suggest like this, instead I ask the OP to change the setting in automated path alias setting, you can easily change the setting to your requirement. Recommending to uninstall the module is definitely the wrong approach! It will heavily affect the SEO if you run a production website for more than 1 month!

Comment: @Bala, thanks for the downvote.  If you believe that disabling a module for two minutes to determine if that particular module is responsible for the problem, will inpact on SEO, then you've got the wrong idea about SEO.  I'm trying to teach the OP a *general* technique for determing if a particular module is responsible for a particular problem.

Comment: I don't know why you are teaching a risky way, instead ask them to check the settings in "automated path alias setting". Still I don't recommend your way, especially to new drupal users.

Comment: @Bala, well it is a technique I use myself on a regular basis for debugging, and it is usully both quicker and safer than poking around with settings to see what happens, since it is so simple to reverse. As for "risky way" you talk about: Is is fictitious that this involves anything risky.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path to the content you create. It's under the "URL path setting" "vertical" tab on each node. However, this can be automated using [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto).

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias.

After installing Pathauto you can manage your URL aliases at:

Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases > Patterns
 (`/admin/config/search/path/patterns`).

Cheers,